# Wildfly 11 load balancing 2 server nodes

Tags: windows, wildfly, load-balancing

I need to be able to redirect to one of 2 server nodes by hitting the load balancer. The load balancer does not need to load balance but failover in case one of the server nodes fail.

I have both server nodes able to connect to the load balancer. For the life of me, I cannot find a solution on how to proceed. I am using wildfly 11 on windows server.

this is the output when loading the load balancer (with the servers running as well) -

```
12:09:24,592 INFO  [io.undertow] (default task-1) UT005053: Registering node Primary, connection: ajp://10.2.133.229:8009/?#
 12:09:24,623 INFO  [io.undertow] (default task-2) UT005045: Registering context /, for node Primary
12:09:24,623 INFO  [io.undertow] (default task-2) UT005045: Registering context /wildfly-services, for node Primary
12:09:30,638 INFO  [io.undertow] (default task-2) UT005053: Registering node Secondary, connection: ajp://10.2.133.230:8009/?#
12:09:30,654 INFO  [io.undertow] (default task-2) UT005045: Registering context /, for node Secondary
12:09:30,670 INFO  [io.undertow] (default task-2) UT005045: Registering context /wildfly-services, for node Secondary
```

My setup is as follows:

```
Load-balancer has an Ip of 10.2.133.228
Server1 has an Ip of 10.2.133.229
Server2 has an Ip of 10.2.133.230
```

Both "Servers" have the same deployed application on both of them.

I would like to input the load-balancer Ip address and hit one of 2 available servers. If one of the 2 servers fail I would like it to failover automatically to the other server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to balance, you can use a reverse proxy, one good option could be Cherokee.

http://cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_proxy.html

It is easy to configure. You can set up a lot of servers to answer every request and when one of these servers fail, the new requests will be sent to another server.

You can install your certificate SSL in the reverse proxy too.

Comment: thanks for the reply but they need to be load balanced.

Comment: In that case, you need to implement a cluster, some master server and slave servers, you can use a load balancer as NGinx, it is very good and the performance is the best now by experience.

Comment: Thanks Milton, would it be possible to use reverse proxy with wildfly loadbalancer profile.xml though?

Comment: You can use reverse proxy without any balance. Every server must be started as a standalone server. Your define the rules to send request to one or another server. This solution is not the best but it works.

Comment: the issue was port assignment total overlook from my end. Thanks a lot. Another question if i can, would I be able to failover an application (war file) located on the primary node only to the other node secondary?